# Logistic Regression Output advice

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I am fairly new to R and have completed a logistic regression in which select cont/cat variables are predicting DV on either good health satisfaction or bad health satisfaction.

However, my coefficient output is primarily negative and intuitively incorrect i.e age 90+ is -1.079 Odds ratio and age 40-49 is 0.41. Could anybody please suggest as to what i have done wrong to make 90 year olds less likely to have bad health than younger populations. Is this potentially a recoding error?

output: (c_Sclfsat1 = reported health 0= bad 1= good)

[image]

Thanks!!!

Comment: First, your model does not say that older people have better health as measured by some objective criterion. It suggests that older people perceive they have better health (perhaps than they would expect given their age). Second, run models with each independent variable separately. There could easily be correlations between the independent variables that are producing the results you are observing,